# Add one key to all values in a list

Tags: python, list

There is a list of email id and need to add key "email" to every elements in a list. Email list:

```
user = ["test@xyz.com","check@xyz.com"]
```

Here email key is to be added and output should be as.
[{'email': 'test@xyz.com'}, {'email': 'check@xyz.com'}]

For this,

```
email_object = {}
email_list = []
user = ["test@xyz.com","check@xyz.com"]

for i in user:
    email_object["email"] = i
    email_list.append(email_object)
print(email_list)
```

Result:

```
 [{'email': 'check@xyz.com'}, {'email': 'check@xyz.com'}]
```

Only last email address in a list is shown in a result. How to show output result as :

```
[{'email': 'test@xyz.com'}, {'email': 'check@xyz.com'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension like the following:

```
users = ["test@xyz.com","check@xyz.com"]
res = [{"email": v} for v in users]
```

This will results in:

```
[{'email': 'test@xyz.com'}, {'email': 'check@xyz.com'}]
```

The problem your experiencing using your code is the fact that you append the same copy of the `email_object` to the list while changing it.

You can modify your code the following to make it work as expected:

```
...
email_list.append(email_object.copy())
...
```